# Training 1D conv model in keras

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train simple !D conv model in keras. I have 1D data in excel file. I am first
reading the data in python. Then I am making the training dataset python. Then I splitting the
dataset into training and testing dataset. But when i trained simple !D con model, I am getting the
error as shown below. Please guide me how to solve this issue.

```
    training_data = []
    def create_training_data():
    for label in labels:
      dir_path = os.path.join(path_dir, label)
      class_num = labels.index(label)
      file_list = os.listdir(dir_path)
    
    for file_name in file_list:
        img_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_name)
        dir_split = dir_path.split('\\')
        
        training_data.append([img_path, class_num])
        
  create_training_data()
  print(len(training_data))
  import random

  random.shuffle(training_data)

  for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print(sample[1])
    X = []
    Y = []

for features, classes in training_data:
  X.append(features)
  Y.append(classes)
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

  len(y_test)
  import numpy as np
  #inp = np.array(X_train)
   #print(inp.shape)
   kernel_size = 3

x = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation="relu")(inp)
x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)


x = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)


x = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)


x = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2)(x)


  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = Dense(4, activation="softmax")(x)

  return Model(inputs=inp, outputs=x)
```

I am getting the following error:

**All inputs to the layer should be tensors**.

How I can solve this problem.

Comment: inp needs to be an input layer (keras.layers.Input)